# Bootstrap Form group

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want this kind of a setup as in the below screenshot.
[image: Required Format]

But currently with the code that I have written, I am getting the below output. I tried various options but unable to get the same output as above.
[image]

**My current HTML Code:**

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label style="" for="inputPackageName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Package Name
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPackageName" placeholder="Package Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <label style="" for="inputApplicationName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Application
                                        Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputApplicationName"
                                            placeholder="Package Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

Any idea as to how to get the required layout as in screenshot. Also how to utilize the white space effectively. i.e. Some labels might require more space, some might require less space. How to have the consistency in bootstrap?

Comment: You code works just fine.. https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/brzLazuc/ check this working example. **Note** resize the result section

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally got a better & easy implementation the same way I wanted.Below is the code!

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-form" role="form" data- toggle="validator" action="blank.html" method="post">
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectID">Project ID </label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="inputProjectID" name="inputProjectID" type="text" placeholder="Your Project ID" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectName">Project Name </label>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
            <input id="inputProjectName" name="inputProjectName" type="text" placeholder="Your Project Name" class="form-control input-md">
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="datepicker">Release Date </label>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
                <input id="datepicker" name="inputReleaseDate" type="text" placeholder="Select Release Date" class="form-control input-md">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputSupervisor">Supervisor </label>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-3-input">
                <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" placeholder="Your Supervisor's Name" class="form-control input-md">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text area -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="inputProjectDesc">Project Description </label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-9-input">
            <textarea style="resize: none;" rows="3" class="form-control" id="inputProjectDesc" name="inputProjectDesc" placeholder="Your Project Description"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't give the class col-sm-2 (in your case) to the labels.
Try to use this layout for the input fields:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>...</label>
        <input class="form-control" .../>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label>...</label>
        <input class="form-control" .../>
     </div>
 </div>
```

This will render a row with 2 columns. To add more rows just copy the layout

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
`.   
     < div class="col-sm-6">
      
        ...
        
     
     
    < div class="col-sm-6">
      
        ...

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 < div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>...</label>
      <input class="form-control" .../>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>...</label>
       <input class="form-control" .../>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-12">
 < div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>...</label>
    <input class="form-control" .../>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score -1):

This should give you what you want (as long as you don't have other CSS rules that could override Bootstrap):

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputProjectId" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProjectId" placeholder="Project ID">
        </div>

        <label for="inputProjectName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProjectName" placeholder="Project Name">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputReleaseDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Release Date</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputReleaseDate" placeholder="Release Date (mm/dd/yyyy)">
        </div>

        <label for="inputSupervisor" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Supervisor</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSupervisor" placeholder="Supervisor">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputProjectDescriptiond" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project Description</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="inputProjectDescriptiond" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Project Description"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just paste this code:

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputProjectID" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Project ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProjectID" placeholder="Project ID">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputProjectName" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Project Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProjectName"
                                placeholder="Project Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputReleaseDate" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Release Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputReleaseDate" placeholder="Release Date (mm/dd/yyyy)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputSupervisor" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Supervisor</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSupervisor" placeholder="Supervisor">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputProjectDescription" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project Description</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="inputProjectDescription" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Project Description"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Hope this will help you!!